# How can I access a class other than though passing in a method?

Tags: java, libgdx

Let us say we have a class called World. Which contains a class called Data. We also have a third class called Input. If Input.clicked(Event event, int x, int y) were to be called I would not be able to access World which means I can't access Data. How do you go about resolving this?

Another way to ask this might be: How can you access something in a method from another class that can't be changed when what you need to access is not final?

Sorry, I am having a hard time explaining this.

**Update bit**: The world class already exists, can't create a new one. It would be inside the Game class.

Here is a code example, not working code. More pseudo.

```
public class World {

  Data data = new Data();
  Input input = new Input();

  public void update(float delta) {
    input.getInput();
    input.makeChangesBasedOnInput();
  }

  public void render(float delta) {
  }
}

public class Data {

  public int importantNumber; // Static is not an option
                              // For me I have to get a user name... but same idea here

  public Data() {
    Random ran = new Random();
    importantNumber = ran.nextInt(1000);
  }

}

public class Input {

  Button button = new Button();

  public Input() { // passing the World class does not work, ex. public Input(World world) {
    button.addListener(new ClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) { // I can't add world here...
        // HERE IS ISSUE
        System.out.println(World.Data.importantNumber);
      }
    }
  }

  public void getInput() {
    // MAGIC
  }

  public void makeChangesBasedOnInput() {
    // MAGIC
  }

}
```

**Update 2:** Here is another example of what I am trying to do with TextButton & ClickListener from libgdx.

statsButton is a TextButton() from libgdx.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say *passing the World class does not work*, well that is probably because you tried to acces a local variable from anonymous function, example:

```
public Input(World world) {
  button.addListener(new ClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
      // error: world is not final
      System.out.println(world.data.importantNumber);
    }
  }
}
```

this is what probably happened (if not, please let me know). In Java 8, `world` would be `effectivly final`, but in Java 7 or earlier, you would have to declare it final explicitly, like

```
public Input(final World world) { ... }
```

Also a common approach is to store your world inside a field:

```
private World world;
public Input(World world) {
  this.world = world;
  ...
}
```

Comment: Ok fine. So I store world inside of input. I would have just passed it though, but lets go with that. Still does not solve the problem. I need to then access world from the ClickListener() from libgdx which is not working when I do this. Let me update with LibGDX example with TextButton and ClickListener classes.

Comment: I take that back, your right about the whole final thing. Thanks!